# Organizing platformer game into classes

Tags: architecture, software-engineering, platformer

I'm making a platformer game and I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how to organize my classes. I'm wondering what the best way to have everything interact would be without passing parameters all over the place. I've heard of MVC, but does this apply? Should I look into it more?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing wrong with passing parameters. The key is to start, dont think about perfect designs, start and refactor once in a while. You learn from making mistakes, so go ahead and make mistakes, dont try to prevent them.

Answer (score 3):

There are no special rules for a platformer vs. any other game in this respect. I suggest that you just start making your game. You'll make a lot of mistakes, but hacking the game together while staying conscious of what one can do better is how I learned to create clean, organized code.

Here are some patterns that you should be aware of when making your game:
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/introduction.html

Two or three games from now, you'll be applying the principles that I linked to, and you'll be organizing your code better as a result of seeing how it all ties together from experience.

Another important point is that many people developing a game in their spare time do not finish it. Hacking your platformer together at the cost of a less than perfect code base might actually allow you to create a finished product. Then you can clean up the engine in version 2.0.

Comment: I'm slowly learning this, I run into so many walls when I try and make the *best* solution for my problem, when I could have solved it in 5 minutes by writing *dirtily*.
But almost always the experience I get after just getting the result, ends up in me being capable of making a solution better than the *best* and *dirty* solutions combined.
So in short, its best to heed this advice and stick to it: `get it done`.